# Laptop held hostage by administrator domain and Bit locker

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, bitlocker

I have a laptop computer that I had when I was working at an IT company. I don´t work there
anymore but I could keep the computer (Lenovo)

Suddenly my wireless internet didn´t work anymore showing error "insert SIM into the mobile broadband device" and month later connectiong to internet with cable got disabled

I don´t know the password to sign in as an administrator on domain and whatever I try to do/install/change settings... everything needs admin rights.

To surf the internet again with the computer I tried to install a new Windows but it´s seems to be protected with Bit Locker, asking for recovery key.

I´ve googled and googled bunch of CMD tricks but most of the shows "system error 5 has occured"

Is there anyway to get the wireless internet to work, change the admin or install new 
Windows? - or should I rather enjoying throwing it of the balcony or set it one fire? :)

Comment: Any reason IT at your old company cannot assist?

Comment: Any reason your old company did not fully wipe the laptop when you left them? Usually company does this by reinstalling the image which was on the laptop when they bought it.  Something which is to the advantage of both the old company and the new owner of the laptop.

Comment: Sounds like you had a 3g/4g Sim Card on the laptop. That costs the IT company each month. You'll have to go to a service provider and get a new sim along with a data plan. It can range on price (~$50.00/month).

Comment: What about the SIM... is there a sim-card like in celluarphones that suddenly stopped working - I was just connected to my home router, not a 3G service?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

1. Call up your company and see if you can get them to remove all of this stuff
2. Wipe the whole drive from another PC, then install Windows (easy, but you lose installed programs, the rest can be backed up)
3. Try a program like [Kon boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) or similar to see if you can just set the admin password so that you can control everything
4. Try a system restore (this may require the admin password)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can download all data that you want to save to an external hard drive, then use a Linux Live CD such as GParted to format the whole disk, deleting any programs that your old company may have installed, then reinstall Windows?